# Boot time Start service save records to database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I want to save records from onStartCommand() of service that starts on boot time, but AsyncTask() cant call that time for db coding.If i not start service on boot time and just start service from application it works fine.

Comment: How can one possibly understand the problem based on your description? Please be more specific, describe your application properly, post some code, help us help you!

Comment: I want to SaveGPSLocation (i.e URLConnection done in AsyncTask) and that service i start at boot time, it should work like onLocationChange, the records should be stored. but i cant do it. even i can not find any exception.